# OpenGL near plane is clipping too much

Tags: c++, opengl, math, camera, clip

I'm having some issues with my camera, where the near plane seems to be too far even when I have it set to 0.1 or lower. It seems like there is already some offset value. So you can't really get close enough an arbitrary object in the scene.

Below is a visual appearance of the bug.
[image]

The black triangle shown is the clipping.
Currently I'm using a perspective matrix and here is the code for that.

```
Matrix4x4 Matrix4x4::Perspective(Float fov, Float aspectRatio, Float near, Float far)
{
    Matrix4x4 result(1.0f);

    Float q = 1.0f / tan(toRadians(0.5f * fov));
    Float a = q / aspectRatio;

    Float b = (near + far) / (near - far);
    Float c = (2.0f * near * far) / (near - far);

    result.elements[0 + 0 * 4] = a;
    result.elements[1 + 1 * 4] = q;
    result.elements[2 + 2 * 4] = b;
    result.elements[2 + 3 * 4] = -1.0f;
    result.elements[3 + 2 * 4] = c;

    return result;
}
```

I don't feel that the bug is from the maths class. This is because the maths code are mainly from another project that I've been working on. And works perfectly fine from there.
I also don't suspect that its the way that I render it (forward renderer). I believe my pointers for that are good since I am able to move and rotate the camera via mouse and keyboard.

But! What I suspect is the buffers. The OpenGL buffers. But I'm not entirely sure.

I hope someone gives me some advice as to how I can hunt and tackle this bug down.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: first of all, you'll have to provide all the other transforms besides the projection matrix (View, World, and whatever else you have). The vertex buffer for the cube is obviously required too

Comment: Do you have a clue as to what problem it might be ?

Comment: @JekasG: Your cube might simply reach beyond Z<=near but we can't tell that without seeing your transformation setup and the cube's vertices. You're looking at the cube along it's diagonal, which length is elongated by a factor of `sqrt(3*1²) = sqrt(3) =~= 1.73`.

Comment: Its not just the cube's diagonal , this is happening , even the edges

Comment: Where is you camera and what near value are you using?

Comment: The cameras position is looking at the cube and the near value is 0.1f

Comment: @JekasG the camera position is? (coordinates) My bet is exactly the same as datenwolf mention. Your cube vertex coordinates are `+/- 1.0` and looking from distance of `1.0` which will intersect all the fragments nearer than `znear`. on the cube diagonal the enlarge factor is up to `sqrt(3)` and on the edges where the clipping starts it at least `sqrt(2)` (square diagonal). To test it try to render sphere instead if not clipping you know it is this ...

Comment: Sorry. I re-read what you said several times and it still hasn't gotten into my head. Sorry. Can you please explain it in a bit more detail ? Also, from what I read, I feel that what's happening in the above photo is normal. Is that right ?

Comment: @JekasG added answer with image may be it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"glEnable(GL_DEPTH_CLAMP)" Solved The Issue

Answer (score 3):

Well one image is worth more then 1000 words so:

[image: cube cut]

As I mentioned in my comments if your cube is half size `r=1.0` and you set up your camera in distance `r` from cube center you still get cut by `z_near` as the cube edges are distant from center in range `<sqrt(2),sqrt(3)>` so all edges turned towards camera will get cut off ...

But also as mentioned this is just guess because you did not provide any test data relevant for this (matrices and mesh content)...

PS on the right side is the cube side view of your camera settings I am guessing you have set. The green `(+/-)Z` is your viewing direction.